# How do I stack duplicate custom list to master list in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, custom-lists

I have duplicate list and I would like that to have rolled up to master list. Any possibilities without using code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Datasheet view and copy the Items to your master list or you can try Export to Excel and update to your master list.